# WinForms, VS2022: ReportViewer Export PDF: How to add a missing font?

Tags: winforms, pdf, reportviewer

I splitted my previous question because the problem shifted.
So how can I add a missing font to the ReportViewer so that the pdf-export is working?
Astonishingly, in the page preview there is no problem to display the report